# What kind of bulbs should I get? My bulbs does not look normal

Tags: bulb

I am in a situation where I need to change bulbs in my bathroom, but my bulbs look weird, and can't find right bulbs for our light.

The bulbs that I took out look like this. There are wires coming out. I had to cut them when I remove the bulbs from a socket.

[image]

We showed the bulbs to Home depo guy. He thinks that I should have removed the base, but I don't see any base.. This is how the socket looks like after I removed the bulbs.

[image]

Will I ever be able to find right bulbs? Can someone please help?

Comment: I bought Phillips PLT 26W/841/A/4P but it did not fit :(

Answer (score 6):

Those are 2 or 4 pin CFL bulbs. Sorta like this:

[image: 4 pin cfl example]

Technically, you should handle them with care, as the contents of the tubes are toxic.

Turn off the power to the light, wear sturdy gloves, and pull the bottom part of the bulb straight out of the socket. (Straight out means the direction that the tubes were going.)

With this end in a plastic baggie, you'll be able to find an appropriate replacement at the hardware store.

Answer (score 5):

What you've done is partially disassembled the bulb itself by splitting the base and leaving part of it behind in the socket.
[image]

You need to remove the rest of the base from the socket before you can replace the bulb.

The Philips bulb you bought is probably correct.
[image]
Note the groove it has across the fat section of its base - that's probably where  you split your old one apart.

Comment: You are right. We bought another bulbs yesterday to try out, but it didn't work. It's because we still have the base stuck to the socket! Thank you!